# Can we get 100 tweets from twitter in less than 1 minute using any API / Library?

Tags: python, twitter, text-mining, data-analysis

I am using the twitter api but its taking about 15 minutes to fetch about 180 tweets about the specified # tag. Is there any way that we boost the tweets number. i want to get about 150 tweets in less than a minute.

Comment: what about using https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written? That will help us fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org) for the library side of things.

Use the official search API for getting the tweets:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23abcd
```

Where the query parameter can be a string or a hashtag. (%23 being the url encoded `#`)
More information is available here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

*Note* : Search API is OAauth authenticated, so you'll need to include your access tokens to the API call.

Comment: what APIs do u refer that may fetch 150 tweets in less than 1 min?

Comment: Use the official search API!